# Summing rows from a MultiIndex pandas df based on index label

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a `pandas.DataFrame` which looks like this:

```
         Probability
0 1 2 3          
C H C C  0.058619
H H C H  0.073274
C H C H  0.195398
C H H H  0.113982
C H H C  0.009770
C C C C  0.087929
H C H H  0.005234
H H H C  0.003664
H H C C  0.021982
C C H C  0.004187
H C H C  0.000449
C C H H  0.048849
H C C C  0.009421
H H H H  0.042743
C C C H  0.293096
H C C H  0.031403
```

The index is a tuple of `len(4)` and its order corresponds to all sequences of length four and a 2 letter alphabet `['H','C']`. What is the best way to sum the rows with a `H` in position `[i for i in df.index]` ?

`df.ix['H'].sum()` is functional but I can't see how to generalize to the 'any case' method. For example, I need to be able to perform the same calculation regardless of how long the sequence is or with more than a 2 letter alphabet. Moreover, the `df.ix['H']` is difficult because it doesn't seem to accept wild cards, i.e. `df.ix['*','H']` for all sequences with `H` in index position 1. Does anybody have any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Setup

To create a dummy data frame which corresponds to your provided example, I used the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

# define sequence and target
sequence = ["H", "C"]
target = "H"

# define shapes
size_col = 4
size_row = 100

# create dummy data and dummy columns
array_indices = np.random.choice(sequence, size=(size_row, size_col))
array_value = np.random.random(size=(size_row, 1))
array = np.concatenate([array_indices, array_value], axis=1)

col_indices = ["Idx {}".format(x) for x in range(size_col)]
col_values = ["Probability"]
columns = col_indices + col_values

# create pandas data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(array, columns=columns)
df[col_values] = df[col_values].astype(float)
```

The resulting `pandas.DataFrame` looks like this:

```
>>> print(df.head())

Idx 0   Idx 1   Idx 2   Idx 3   Probability
  C       C       C       H     0.892125
  C       H       C       H     0.633699
  C       C       C       C     0.228546
  H       C       H       C     0.766639
  C       H       C       C     0.379930
```

The only difference to your data frame is the reset index (you get the same when using `df.reset_index()`).

### Solution

Now, to get the sums of the rows with a target value for all indices, you may use the following:

```
bool_indices = df[col_indices] == target
result = bool_indices.apply(lambda x: df.loc[x, col_values].sum())
```

**First**, you create a new data frame with boolean values which correspond to each index column containing the target value for each row.

**Second**, you use these boolean series as index columns to define a subset of your actual value column and finally apply an arbitrary method like sum() on it.

The result is the following:

```
>>> print(result)

                   Idx 0       Idx 1      Idx 2       Idx 3
Probability     23.246007   23.072544   24.775996   24.683079
```

This solution is flexible in regard to your input sequence, the target and the shape of your data.

In addition, if you want to use slicing with *wildcards*, you can use the pandas.IndexSlice on your original data frame example like:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice

# to get all rows which have the "H" at second index
df.loc[idx[:, "H"], :]

# to get all rows which have the "H" at third index
df.loc[idx[:, :, "H"], :]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution from what pansen suggested is to use `pandas.groupby`

```
    levels=[0,1,2,3]
    for i in range(levels):
        for j in df.groupby(level=i):
            MI=pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([i,j[0]])
            val= float(j[1].sum())
            df_l.append( pandas.DataFrame([val],index=MI))
    return pandas.concat(df_l)
```